# React div scrollbar start from bottom + loading more messages from db with Redux

Tags: reactjs, scroll, react-redux, infinite-scroll

I'm trying to implement infinite scrolling in my private messages page. So when user scroll to top (in the div) it will load more messages.

I have a problem in the first load.

It loads all the messages before scroll is happening.

There is a way to make the scrollbar start from the bottom?

I'm using Redux-Saga to load more messages for conversation component (`loadMoreMessages`) and the reducer updates `messages` state.

Here is the code:

```
const ConversationComp = (props) => {
    const {
        loadMoreMessages,
        messages
    } = props;

    const ref = useRef(null);

    useLayoutEffect(() => {
        const elem = ref.current;
        if (elem) {
            console.log("scrolling to bottom");
            elem.scrollTop = elem.scrollHeight;
        }
    }, []);

    useEffect(() => {
        console.log("loading more messages");
        loadMoreMessages();
    }, []);


    const onScrollHandler = (e) => {
        const elem = e.target;
        const threshold = 30;
        if (elem.scrollTop < threshold) {
            // reached top
            loadMoreMessages();
        }
    };

    return (
        <div onScroll={onScrollHandler} ref={ref}>
                {
                    messages.map(m => {
                        ...
                    })
                }
        </div>
    );
}
```

The desired behavior:

1. Load first batch of messages
2. scrollbar is at the bottom
3. When user scroll to top it loads more messages

Any ideas?